# Microsoft Dynamics C5 integration with external system

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, c5

I am currently on a project integrating [Microsoft Dynamics C5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_C5) with an external system. ie, when an item is created on Dynamics C5 i want the item to be created in an external system (which has a feature rich API). Can someone give an idea how can we manage it from C5 part, can we directly access it from C5 database using c# or is there a concept like web-hooks on C5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are possible different solutions, I can give you an idea, I've implemented before. You can create custom entities, where to store instance id of e.g. contacts which you want create or update in external system. Register insert / update plugins, which will create new instance of your custom entity each time you have updated contact. And next some process will take updated id's, create contacts in external system and delete / mark as processed you custom entity instances.

Comment: The Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Software Development Kit (SDK) - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004 has lots of examples